# How can I test that the output cache is working properly in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Should it still be doing SQL queries in the profiler?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, your question is not very clear. What exactly do you want to know and do you have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output cache is working you can use firebug to check that the page sizes are smaller when turned on.